# Pedaling in Chopin Nocturne in C# minor, measures 9-18

Tags: piano, keyboard-pedals

What is the pedaling going to be for the rest of the below sheet? Is it going to be like measure 8, or it is going to be like measures 1-7? Sometimes it shows the pedal sign like in measure 16, which confuses me about what the previous measure is going to be.

[image: Chopin Nocturne in C# minor, measure 1-18]

Comment: You can continue with the pedal in the same style:  4 quavers = 1 Ped. (except when there’s no chord change in a bar: 8 quavers = 1 Ped.) But take care in bars 16th triplets and 32nds. Maybe you better make pedal steps each quarter note.

Answer (score 2):

The logic of pedaling is keeping the delay according to the harmony. In this example the chords last 2 beats, then you hold 2 beats, if the harmony lasts 4 beats you can hold the pedal 4 beats as assigned, but also 2 beats would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

- `measures 9-10, 12-14, 18: pedal as in measure 5.`<sup>1</sup>
- `measures 11, 16, 17: pedal as in measure 16.`<sup>2</sup>
- `measure 15: pedal with each beat or even with each left-hand eight-note.`<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Each four-note grouping in the left hand represents a single harmony. In these measures, the melody also moves in two-beat segments. Thus by changing the pedal twice in each measure, both the harmony and melody remain "clean". In measure 12 the pedal change is particularly important so that the melody note on beats 1 and 2 doesn't bleed over into the rest on beat 3.

<sup>2</sup> In these measures, the melody and harmony remain static until the final beat (or half-beat). It's better here to keep the pedal through the measure to help sustain the long melody notes. The reason the pedal in measure 16 is marked even though the surrounding measures are not is because the surrounding measures are left to the experience and interpretation of the performer, but measure 16, the editor believes, should be pedaled in the specific way indicated.

<sup>3</sup> Because the melody is ornamental and scalar, you need frequent pedal changes to prevent blurring of the sound. I prefer half-pedal, changing at each eight-note in the left hand, but pedaling once per beat may also be sufficient.

---

NOTE: There is, IMO, an error in the pedal marking measure. The pedal release mark should be at the end of the second beat, not the end of the measure. The earlier release allows for the indicated rest in the right hand.