# Chopin Nocturne in C# minor Pedaling (Henle Verlag ed. with very few pedal markings)

Tags: piano, keyboard-pedals

I saw [another question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/108436/pedaling-in-chopin-nocturne-in-c-minor-measures-9-18) related to pedaling for this piece, but that one uses a different edition (not sure what edition). My Henle edition ([cover picture here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/133469/chopin-waltz-in-b-minor-op-69-no-2-measures-1314-different-versions)) has no pedal in the intro part, and only three pedal markings until measure 19. What's the assumption for the omitted parts?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR

- Pedaling in the introduction is up to the performer.
- Pedaling for the remainder of the piece follows the pattern set in the first markings.

---

The first three pedal markings are there to set the pattern for the rest of the piece. The intention is that one continues to pedal each half-measure. Exceptions would be left up to the experience and musical intention of the performer.

I also own a Henle edition of this Nocturne, which includes two versions of the piece: the one posted in the question, and a second one with no pedal markings at all. The reason for the two versions is that there is no known copy in Chopin's handwriting, and there are two different manuscripts by different engravers, both of whom, it seems, Henle considers reliable sources, plus the Polish First Edition (PFE).

The sources for this Nocturne are available at the [Online Chopin Variorum Edition](https://chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/browse/). In the list of works, look for "Lento con gran espressione". Of the three that show the first measures, none have pedal markings in the introduction, and only PFE has pedal marks in the first measures of the main melody. Interestingly, they're slightly different than the Henle pedaling in that the third pedal mark extends for the entire measure rather than the half measure.

Since none of the sources indicate pedaling in the intro measures, that is left up to the interpreter.

Comment: @GrandAdagio Up to you, but, IMO, yes.

Comment: Aaron I just noticed in my Henle book a picture (too obvious for me to have noticed!) of a copy by Chopin's sister, which seems to be what this edition is based on (same three measures with pedal markings).

Comment: Aaron or anyone else: in Measure 5, according to this score, there is no tie between the first two notes (C), doesn't it mean I should play the C key twice? But I listend to some recordings and all had the C pressed without release untill the B note, why? (maybe I'm being very dumb here--maybe a tie is between two different measures? But then How to notate the case when you play the C twice?)

Comment: @GrandAdagio Some editions indicate a tie. See, for example, various editions on  [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Nocturne_in_C-sharp_minor,_B.49_(Chopin,_Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric)).

Comment: Thanks. I have yet to hear a recording that played repeated C.

Comment: I added another image, of the measure 19, where the second Ped has no * following it. Does it mean to release immediately after the very next note (G), then repeat the same for the next measure?